# How can I access the raw pixel data of an opengl es 2 off screen render buffer?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I can render to the screen but I would like to be able to access the raw pixels that have been rendered by the shader. The only way I know how is to use glReadPixels off of the screen, but I would like to access them before they are draw to screen in order to save frames to disk.

Specifically I want to use shaders to process images that are never displayed: 1)grab image from disk 2)render it 3)output back to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to render to the offscreen texture as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649222/opengl-es-render-to-texture-then-draw-texture)?

Comment: yes I have. Is glCopyTexSubImage2D the command I would use to grab the raw pixel data from the off screen render buffer?

Comment: This will only copy data between two textures. Use glReadPixels to read data to the buffer and store it to disk.