# Draw text in iPhone openGL ES using just objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es

A need to draw some text in openGL and then make rotations and translations over it. Need to use just objective-c. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

Use Photoshop or something to create a texture file like below.

```
|ABCDEFGH|
|IJKLMNOP|
|QRSTU...|

sample.png
```

Calculate UV position of each character.

```
float eachCharHeight = 0.125f;
float eachCharWidth = 0.125f;
char charToDraw = 'a';
int indexOfChar = charToDraw - 65; // 'a' = 65
float uValueForCharA = (float)(indexOfChar / 8) * eachCharHeight;
float vValueForCharA = (float)(indexOfChar % 8) * eachCharWidth;
```

Set texcoords and draw.

```
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(...);  // or translate

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(texture);

float vertices[8] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, ...};
float texcoords[8] = {uValueForCharA, vValueForCharA, 
                      uValueForCharA + eachCharWidth, ...};

...

glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there are basically three ways to do it either you can render the text as a texture ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024603/opengl-es-render-to-texture)) or you can use the 2-d graphics library ([Quartz](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_text/dq_text.html)) mixed with your opengl or finally you can use e.g. UILabel to display the text on top of your opengl output.

Comment: The problem is that I need to draw text as an object and then rotate and translate it. 2D solutions are solutions. Thanks any way :)