# GLImageProcessing Multiple Filters?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, filter

I have read through this question here:  [Can example "GLImageProcessing" work with multi filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375479/can-example-glimageprocessing-work-with-multi-filters)  However, I still do not understand how to edit the sample code for GLImageProcessing to support multiple filters.  Here is the code that I am doing now in drawGL of Imaging.c

Any help?

```
void drawGL(int wide, int high, float val, int mode)
{
    GLuint ResultFBO;
    GLuint ResultTexture;
    static int prevmode = -1;
    typedef void (*procfunc)(V2fT2f *, float);

    typedef struct {
        procfunc func;
        procfunc degen;
    } Filter;

    const Filter filter[] = {
        { brightness             },
        { contrast               },
        { extrapolate, greyscale },
        { hue                    },
        { extrapolate, blur      }, // The blur could be exaggerated by downsampling to half size
    };
#define NUM_FILTERS (sizeof(filter)/sizeof(filter[0]))
    rt_assert(mode < NUM_FILTERS);


    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrthof(0, wide, 0, high, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glScalef(wide, high, 1);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Input.texID);

    // Remember the FBO being used for the display framebuffer
    glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING_OES, (GLint *)&SystemFBO);

    // Create the texture and the FBO the will hold the result of applying the first filter
    glGenTextures(1, &ResultTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ResultTexture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, wide, high, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &ResultFBO);
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, ResultFBO);
    glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_TEXTURE_2D, ResultTexture, 0);

    // bind the result FBO
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, ResultFBO);


    // apply 1st filter
    glViewport(0, 0, wide, high);
    filter[mode].func(flipquad, val);

    // restore original frame buffer object
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, SystemFBO);

    // use ResultTexture as input for the 2nd filter
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ResultTexture);

    // apply 2nd filter
    glViewport(0, 0, wide, high);
    filter[2].func(flipquad, val);

    glCheckError();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extend this scheme by alternating between two buffers:

```
GLuint stageTextures[2];
glGenTextures(2, stageTextures);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, stageTexture[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, wide, high, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, stageTexture[1]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, wide, high, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

GLuint stageFBO[2];
glGenFramebuffersOES(2, stageFB0);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, stageFBO[0]);
glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_TEXTURE_2D, stageTexture[0], 0);    

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, stageFBO[1]);
glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_TEXTURE_2D, stageTexture[1], 0);    

// bind stage 1, sourcing stage 0
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, stageFBO[1]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, stageTexture[0]);

// apply 1st filter
glViewport(0, 0, wide, high);
filter[mode].func(flipquad, val);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // must unbind texture before FBO with that texture attached can be bound


// bind stage 0, sourcing stage 1
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, stageFBO[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, stageTexture[1]);

// apply 2nd filter
glViewport(0, 0, wide, high);
filter[mode].func(flipquad, val);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // must unbind texture before FBO with that texture attached can be bound

// bind stage 1, sourcing stage 0
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, stageFBO[1]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, stageTexture[0]);

// apply 3rd filter
glViewport(0, 0, wide, high);
filter[mode].func(flipquad, val);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // must unbind texture before FBO with that texture attached can be bound

// and so on. finally

// Bind SystemFBO so the screen is the target, sourcing stage 0/1
// (depending on if a even or odd number of filters involved)
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, SystemFBO);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, stageTexture[...]); // set to follow the scheme above

// apply n-th filter
glViewport(0, 0, wide, high);
filter[mode].func(flipquad, val);
```

Comment: So where exactly would this go?  I replaced everything starting from "// Remember the FBO being used for the display framebuffer" and down in my code with yours and still no luck.

Comment: In the last step you have to draw to the screen of course, instead of the framebuffer. I edited that code example.

Comment: I'm still getting a dark black image when I first load it and then when I move the slider it's black to the left and just white to the right.  On some other settings like Hue, the image is there but shown twice...one of them being flipped.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @Flipper: I can think of a number of things. The fact that you can see something means, that the filter chain as it is, is working. Now you're probably running into some unfortunate combination and ordering of filters. Since I neither have an iOS device nor some emulator at hand it's rather difficult to reproduce.

Comment: @datenwolf I was getting the same problem using the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375479/can-example-glimageprocessing-work-with-multi-filters   But is the only difference between the codes that yours supports n filters?

Comment: @Flipper: I really can't tell. Also those code snippets don't contain the actual filter code, they just reference some functions. It would be good if you either added those, too, or at least gave a URL where I can get the original code you adjusted. Then I could port this to PC based OpenGL and do tests on this.

Comment: The code can be found here:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html   And the drawGL function is found in Imaging.c.

Comment: @Flipper: The original code uses auxiliary helper textures, which use has not been visible in your code snippet(s). This changes the whole approach to be taken! Give me some time to port that program to my system and tinker with it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to combine multiple filters and here is complete method based on the suggestions made here.

```
void drawGL(int wide, int high, float val, int mode)
{

    static int prevmode = -1;
    typedef void (*procfunc)(V2fT2f *, float);

    typedef struct {
            procfunc func;
            procfunc degen;
    } Filter;

    const Filter filter[] = {
            { brightness             },
            { contrast               },
            { extrapolate, greyscale },
            { hue                    },
            { extrapolate, blur      },        // The blur could be exaggerated by downsampling to half size
    };
    #define NUM_FILTERS (sizeof(filter)/sizeof(filter[0]))
    rt_assert(mode < NUM_FILTERS);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrthof(0, wide, 0, high, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glScalef(wide, high, 1);

glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING_OES, (GLint *)&SystemFBO);
// Create the texture and the FBO the will hold the result of applying the first filter
glGenTextures(1, &ResultTexture.texID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ResultTexture.texID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, wide, high, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &ResultTextureFBO);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, ResultTextureFBO);
glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_TEXTURE_2D, ResultTexture.texID, 0);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, ResultTextureFBO);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Input.texID);

    glViewport(0, 0, wide, high);
brightness(flipquad, val);
    glCheckError();

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, SystemFBO);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ResultTexture.texID);

    glViewport(0, 0, wide, high);
hue(fullquad, val);
    glCheckError();    
}
```